# Complexity, both time and space

Tags: java, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am new to the forum, so I hope I am doing this right.

I am struggling with figuring out bigO complexity. Specifically time complexity.
I am working on a recursive program right now that calls itself twice each recurse.
Example:

> compute(i,j)
>
> *edge checks*
>
> x = (compute(i-1, j) + compute(i, j-1)) /2;
>
> return x;

I think this is `O(2^n)` time, because each call produces two more. Is this correct?
Is it the same for complexity?

Comment: *n* being what?

Comment: Without specifying what the `edge checks` are, this is an algorithm that does not return i.e. infinitely recursive.

Comment: Yes, I left them out as not to write the whole code. But basically, the edge checks handle when i or j reaches 0. They set x to either 1 or 0, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use array of int or var-args like compute(int... val)
send 4 argument 2 for first operation last 2 for second operation your performing inside this method.

return addition of two operation from that method.

so you will get the O(n) time.

Comment: Question was not **how to achieve O(n) complexity**. Question really is **Is it  O(n) or not**.

Comment: brother you calling your method twice so it's simple that it's not O(n) it's O(n 2) n square

Comment: Correct. I don't want to optimize the code, as that would simplify the process of figuring this out. But I would simply like to know what the complexity of the "as is" code is.

Comment: just approve my answer brother so i'll get some score

Comment: So your saying my code right now is O(2^n)? Or O(n^2)?

Comment: it is O(n Square).  O(n^2)  means order of n with logarithmic output of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Time is `O(2^(m+n))`, and space is `O(1)`.

**For Time complexity:**

- `O(m,1) = O(m-1, 1) + O(1,1) = O(m-2,1) + 2O(1,1) = ... = O(m)`
- `O(m,2) = O(m,1) + O(m-1,2) = O(m) + O(m-1, 1) + O(m-2,2) = ... = O(m) + O(m-1) + ... + O(1) + O(1,2) = O(m^2)`
- `O(m,3) = O(m,2) + O(m-1,3) = O(m^2) + O(m-1, 2) + O(m-2,3) = ... = O(m^2) + - O((m-1)^2) + ... + O(1^2) + O(1,3) = O(2^m)`
- `O(m,4) = O(m,3) + O(m-1,4) = O(2^m) + O(m-1, 3) + O(m-3,4) = ... = O(2^m) + O(2^(m-1)) + ... + O(2^1) + O(1,4) = O(2^(m+1))`
- `O(m,5) = O(m,4) + O(m-1,5) = O(2^(m+1)) + O(m-1, 4) + O(m-3,5) = ... = O(2^(m+1)) + O(2^(m)) + ... + O(2^3) + O(1,5) = O(2^(m+2))`
- ...
- `O(m,n) = O(2^(m+n))`

**For Space complexity:**

it does not use ex space. it is `O(1)`

### P.S.

**optimize**

```
def compute(i,j):
    result = [[0 for x in range(i)] for y in range(j)]
    for x in rangex(i):
        for y in xrange(j):
            if x == 0 or y == 0:
                result[x][y] = value(x,y); // compute(i,j) and (i,j) is edge
            else:
                result[x][y] = (result[x][y-1] + result[x-1][y]) / 2
    return result[i-1][j-1]
```

This is `O(m*n)` time, and `O(m*n)` space.